# Interesting random walk question with differing probabilities

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider a random walk on the integers on the interval $[-N, N].$ For each $n \in [-N, 0],$ the walk is a simple symmetric random walk. For each $n \in [1, N]$, the probability of moving to the right is $1/4$ and the probability of moving to the left is $3/4.$ If the random walk starts at $0$, I want to show that as $N \rightarrow \infty,$ the probability of reaching the left end before the right end tends to $1.$

I know there are a lot ways to solve this, but I wanted to see if my argument was correct.

Shift the random walk up to $[0,2N]$ so then the random walk starts at $N.$ Now, $\text{just}$ consider the random walk on $[N, 2N].$ Then,
$$P( \text{random walk ever reaches $2N$ starting at $N$}) = \left ( \frac{p}{q} \right ) ^N = \left ( \frac{1}{3} \right ) ^ N \rightarrow 0 \ \text{as} \ N \rightarrow \infty.$$

Since the random walk below $N$ is just a simple symmetric random walk, it is recurrent and thus
$$ P( \text{random walk reaches $2N$ before 0}) \leq P( \text{random walk ever reaches $2N$ starting at $N$}) \rightarrow 0 \ \text{as} \ N \rightarrow \infty.$$
Thus,
$$P( \text{random walk reaches $0$ before $2N$}) \rightarrow 1 \ \text{as} \ N \rightarrow \infty.$$
Is this idea valid?

Comment: When $n=-N$ or $n=N,$ the walk can go in only one direction and still stay in $[-N,N].$ It doesn't really matter to the problem, but you should restrict the steps to $n\in[-(N-1),0]$ and $n\in[1,n-1]$ and just halt when you get to $\pm n.$ Or you can not explicitly mention the range $[N,-N],$ and just ask whether it gets to $N$ or $-N$ first.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sure, but is the argument correct?

Comment: "Sure but is the argument correct?" Is in general a rude question here. It is demanding work when I have already seen the question. You are asking volunteers to help you, remember, and sometimes I help with an answer, sometimes I help by suggesting a clearer way to write the question. Demanding an answer is not the best approach.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The math stack exchange is for questions. My question is "Is this idea valid?" It is a yes or no question. I did not ask for any additional ways to solve this problem, any alternative methods, or any ways to rewrite the problem. I asked a yes or no question.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that you can separate the two walks the way you've done. You might be able to do something like, "Let $p$ be the probability, starting at $1,$ that you reach $N$ before you come back to $0.$ Let $q$ be the probability, starting at $-1$ that you reach $-N$ before $0.$ Then the probability of reach $N$ first is an infinite series in terms of $p,q.$

Comment: Ah, I see, you've doubled down on the rudeness. I know your question, and I've been thinking about it. Nagging me and implying that I haven't read the question is not a good way to get people to volunteer their time to help you.

Comment: There are a lot of polite ways to reply to suggestions for how to write the question more clearly. One of them is to take the suggestion and edit the question. One is to acknowledge the suggestion. One response which is not polite is to just demand they answer your question.

Comment: It's not clear how you get the right side eventually reaching $2N$ is probability $(p/q)^N.$ The right side never gets below $N,$ so, at some point the random process with eventually reach $2N.$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can so naively split the walk into two walks.

There is a way to split the walks, but it requires a little more work.

Let a walk on the integers start at $1.$ Let $r$ be the probability on each step that you add $-1,$ with $+1$ being probability $1-r.$

Let $q_{N,r}$ be the probability of reaching $N$ before reaching $0.$

Then if $p_N$ is the probability for your question or reaching $N$, then the probability that starting at $0$, you get to $N$ without passing through $0$ again is $\frac12q_{N,3/4}.$ The probability that you pass through $0$ again is $\frac12\left(1-q_{N,1/2}+1-q_{N,3/4}\right).$

So you get: $$p_{N}=\frac12 q_{n,3/4}+\frac12(2-q_{N,1/2}-q_{N,3/4})p_N$$ Solving, you get: $$p_N=\frac{q_{N,3/4}}{q_{N,3/4}+q_{N,1/2}}$$so we need to somehow get bounds on $q_{N,r}.$

We will do so by induction.

When $N=1,$ $q_{1,r}=1,$ since you are already at $N.$

Now we try to compute $q_{N+1,r}$ in terms of $q_{N,r}.$

If you are at $2,$ the probability you reach $N+1$ before $1$ is just $q_{N,r}.$ So:

$$q_{N+1,r}=(1-r)q_{N,r}+(1-r)(1-q_{N,r})q_{N+1,r}$$

Solving again, we get:

$$q_{N+1,r}=\frac{(1-r)q_{N,r}}{1-(1-r)(1-q_{N,r})}=\frac{q_{N,r}}{\frac r{1-r}+q_{N,r}}$$

When $r=1/2,$ $\frac r{1-r}=1,$ and you get: $$q_{N,1/2}\geq \frac1{2^{N-1}}$$

When $r=3/4,$ $\frac{r}{1-r}=3,$ and you get: $$q_{N,3/4}\leq \frac1{3^{N-1}}$$

From here, you get: $$p_N=\frac{q_{N,3/4}}{q_{N,3/4}+q_{N,1/2}}\leq \left(\frac23\right)^{N-1}\to 0.$$